# Show Found Row and Null Row For Same Shooter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a scoring system for hitting a target in separate quarters of a year. So a person can shoot at a target and score points based on where they hit the target. Each quarter of the year the score should display 0 before they shoot. I have a table for the shooter information, table for each quarter and a table for the scores to be kept in. I need a query or view that will show the shooter score for the quarter if its there but also show the shooter with no score if they haven't shot yet if that makes sense.

Current Output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

I want the next line to show in the query result so that I can select it when the user entering the scores selects a quarter that is not equal to 1 in this example.

Comment: Post the query that returns your Current Output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union your output with the following select

```
<your select here> 
Union
select distinct shooter, null, 0
from yourTable
order by shooter, score desc
```